# Backbone view event redirect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to move to another page when the event is triggered in a View of Backbone.

```
events: {
    'click .btn': 'signin'
},
render: function() {
    tmp = this.template();
    this.$el.html(tmp);
},
signin: function() {
    var logi = document.forms['signin']['name'].value;
    var mail = document.forms['signin']['email'].value;
    var passwd = document.forms['signin']['pass'].value;
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(passwd).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    var tkn = Math.random(9) * 123123123;
    _this.navigate('#', true);
    var user = new User({
        'login': logi,
        'email': mail,
        'pass': hash,
        'token': tkn.toString(),
        'recovery': null,
        'img': 'default.png'
    });
    //var user = new User({ 'user': logi, 'pass': hash });
    user.save({
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res.res);
        },
        error: function(res) {
            alert(res.res);
        },
        wait: true
    });
```

In my testing, this does not work. Can anyone help me understand why?

The important code is `_this.navigate('#', true)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the url you can do

```
router.navigate('url');
```

If you also wish to call the router's method for this url, you have to set the option trigger to true :

```
router.navigate("url", {trigger: true});
```

Anyway, you should call router.navigate at the end of your fonction, so your user get actually created.

Your view should then be updated by your router method for this url.